# Anyone know of a good unsupported way of getting EBS snaphots into AWS glacier storage?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, snapshot, amazon-glacier

I'm trying to store some important snapshots as cheaply as I can .I wanted to move them into glacier but AWS say its not supported. I wonder is there anyone out there that was able to get around this

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well, it's not supported by AWS.

If it's only the files you're after - you could store those separately in S3 and move them to Glacier from there. But you can't create an EC2 instance or EBS Volume from that.

Snapshots can get expensive, but at least you'll only pay for the delta for your next snapshot...

Comment: yes you're right, it would be too much of a pain if I wanted to create an EC2 and have the data available. thanks